# Слетели библиотеки после обновления Android Studio

Tags: android-studio

Здравствуйте уважаемые форумчане!
На свою голову обновил Android Studio и у меня слетели библиотеки Fabrico, я даже не понимаю почему?
Вот эти библиотеки:

```
import com.crashlytics.android.Crashlytics;
import io.fabric.sdk.android.Fabric;
```

Вот gradle: https://gist.github.com/Maxim1234567/0babe6d34961ebeb3a3ed8b482b8f5aa

Но самое удивительно компилируется все без проблем! Кто-нибудь сталкивался с этой проблемой?

Comment: Что в данном случае означает "слетели"?

Comment: Cannot resolve symbol